# how to invoke full calendar in ionic 2

Tags: angular, calendar, fullcalendar, ionic2

I am trying to invoke full calendar on clicking a button according to this documentation http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/calendar/

i created a new project and installed this plugin after deplying the project into my device i am getting scuccess callback of numm but i am not able to see the calender in my UI

here is my code for .ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {Calendar} from 'ionic-native';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  calender(){

    Calendar.createCalendar('MyCalendar').then(
      (msg) => { console.log("scuccess"+msg); },
      (err) => { console.log("error"+err); }
    );
  }

}
```

here is my html part

```
<button (click)="calender()" ion-button full>clickme</button>
```

can any one help how to get the full callender ui and i am not sure why i am getting null in my console.log of `chorem://inspect`

Comment: did you try calling inside `this.platform.ready().then`?

Comment: @SurajRao no i will try now and let you know

Comment: @SurajRao yes i tried now but still same result

Comment: According to [plugin docs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin) you need to have a few settings in config.xml..

Comment: which device . version of OS?

Comment: Yes I checked with GitHub everything is correct

Comment: I am using 6.ov and moto e3 I am not facing any errors @suraj rao

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132088/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-suraj-rao).

Comment: found a github example https://github.com/Webaxx/ionic2-calendar though it uses ionic beta, it should work

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the calendar to view it.

```
public openCalendar():void{ 
Calendar.openCalendar(this.startDate); 
}
```

In the html:

```
<button (click)="openCalendar()" ion-button full>clickme</button>
```

Check [example here](https://github.com/Webaxx/ionic2-calendar/blob/master/app/pages/page1/page1.html)